# How do I milk a cow?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I am making a farm with a barn and everything. I have sheep for shearing and chicken for... well, chicken (and eggs) and I'm wondering if you can milk a cow.

If so, how can I milk cows?

Comment: [Wiki](http://minecraft.gamepedia.com/) and search Cows or Milk

Answer (score 6):

Create a [Bucket](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Bucket), and Right-Click the cow with the bucket to get a Bucket of Milk.

Drinking Milk won't fill the hunger bar, but it will remove any active effects on your player (such as Poison, Hunger and even positive effects like Strength).

Milk can also be used as an ingredient to make Cake.

You can read more about [Cows](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Cow) and [Milk](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Milk) on the Minecraft Wiki

Comment: I tried and i got no milk :|

Comment: @craftern3rdgurl In the past, I've had greater success obtaining milk by aiming at the lower half of the cow (while holding an empty bucket) - particularly if I aim at their udders.

Comment: OK ill try that

Answer (score 0):

## Milk from Cows

Milk is a type of "drinking object" in Minecraft. It cures the players negative effects such as poison, and hunger. But beware it also move positive effects! You can also use milk for crafting cake, requires 3 milk buckets.

To milk a cow, you to make a bucket using 3 iron ingots in the crafting table. Then find a cow and Right-Click the cow to get a Milk Bucket.

## Mooshrooms

You can also milk Mooshrooms using a bowl made of 3 wooden planks [Any type]. When you milk them, you get Mushroom Stew which you can eat for a few hunger points. Mooshrooms are found in the mushroom biome, and island where there are mushroom trees and some normal world stuff like caves.

Comment: You have way too many videos in your answer. I'd recommend trimming it down to a single video that helps explain your answer.

Comment: @Frank okay I edited it.